# Як правильно: бИрка чи бІрка?

Tags: вибір-слова, іменники

До сьогодні була впевнена, що правильно використовувати лише слово ***бІрка***. Про це пише й [Словник іншомовних слів](http://jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Qry=%E1%B3%F0%EA%E0):

> **Бірка**
>
> 1. Паличка з дерева або бамбука з нанесеними на неї зарубками, якими фіксувалися суми кредиту або грошовий борг, а також зобов'язання у натуральній формі. Б. розщеплювалася по довжині на частини для кредитора і боржника.
>
> *2. Пластинка або паперовий листок з інформацією про вантаж, товар і т. п.*

Проте сьогодні прочитала у романі Сергія Бута “Листи з того світу” (с. 76) таке:

> Орієнтуватись у цих паперових мурах допомагали червоні ***БИРКИ***, що, мов морські буї, стирчали з акуратно поскладаних тек. На ***БИРКАХ*** здебільшого зазначались роки, але траплялися й такі, що мали на собі літери.

Зайшла у [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4132&page=156), проте тут подано лише “бирка” і з такими значеннями:

> **БИ́РКА 1**, и, ж.
>
> 1. Однорічна вівця; ярка.
> 2. лайл. Про нікчемну, погану жінку.
> 3. Овеча шкура; смушок.
>
> **БИ́РКА 2**, и, ж.
>
> 1. *іст.* Паличка або дощечка, на якій робили нарізки для лічби, підрахунків у господарстві.
> 2. Невеличка дощечка або металева бляшка з номером або написом, яку прив'язують до шиї тваринам, а також пластикова або паперова етикетка, яку прикріплюють до різних товарів,  тари, експонатів і т. ін.

Однак значення цих омонімів не зовсім підходять для контексту, що вище подавала.

То як все-таки правильно, *бИрка чи бІрка?*

Comment: А чим «паперова етикетка, яку прикріплюють до різних товарів, тари, експонатів і т. ін.» не підходить до контексту?

Comment: Але ж є ще значення слова бірка "паперовий листок з інформацією про вантаж, товар і т. п". Тому і запитую, яке з них справді має бути, бірка чи бирка.

Comment: Я мав на увазі речення «Однак значення цих омонімів не зовсім підходять для контексту, що вище подавала» (мені здалося, «паперова етикетка, яку прикріплюють до різних товарів, тари, експонатів і т. ін.» цілком підходить, хоча можу помилятися).

Comment: мені здалося, що "паперова етикетна" вжито у значенні "цінник", оскільки йдеться про товари, тари.... Хоча теж можу помилятись.

Comment: А, все, зрозумів.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Знайшла  інформацію, що правильно вживати **«бирка»** у [Волощак М. Неправильно-правильно. Довідник з українського слововживання](https://bitter-onion.livejournal.com/107053.html):

> Табірна **бірка** ― Табірна **бирка**

У [Вікісловнику](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2) в порадах перекладу, також знаходимо варіант **«бирка»**:

> Переклади mark/label/tag у загальній англійській, як і українській ці слова дуже близькі: "label" = "tag" = "mark" та "ярлик" = "**бирка"** = "етикетка", "мітка".

На [Офіційному сайті української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/ja/jarlik/50-1-0-4979):

> Синонiми до слова ЯРЛИК: (на товарі) наліпка, етикетка, (прив'язаний) **бирка**.

І остаточну інформацію знаходимо в [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53392/26799.html):

> **БІРКА**
>   правильніше: **бирка**.

Очевидно, нормативні 2 варіанти слововживання, однак на 1 місці – **бирка.**

Comment: Я б не сказав, що «бірка» нормативне.

Comment: Мені теж так здається. Але я не знайшла ніяких підтверджень. А слово "правильніше" у Словопедії дає підставу вважати, що 2 варіанти можна вживати.  Якщо знайдете якесь підтвердження в офіційних джерелах, щодо правильності вашої думки, було б чудово.

Comment: Не зовсім так. Словопедія передруковує багато джерел. У цьому випадку вона посилається на «Уроки державної мови» (з газети «Хрещатик»). Дивимося [офіційний сайт (чи, можливо, інший сайт, що теж їх передруковує)](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/204.htm): «Одним рядком. НЕПРАВИЛЬНО: <…> БІРКА <…>. ПРАВИЛЬНО: <…> БИРКА <…>».

Answer (score -2):

Цікаво. Лінгвістичний переклад букви И з російської пишеться як буква І. Тому якщо російською написано БИРКА, то логічно, що українською це буде БІРКА.
Бо якби українською буква І писалася як російська буква Ы, то тоді б переклад слова БЫРКА українською логічно б писався БИРКА. І це було б правильно. А так, як пише БИРКА, то беззаперечно і безсумнівно це слово перекладається як БІРКА.
Хіба що слово БИРКА вживалося в Україні - Київській Русі ще задовго до того як появилася Московія і виникла російська мова. Якщо ці докази десь у літописах є, тоді я згідна називати БІРКУ БИРКОЮ.

Comment: Так розумію, мусимо писати *піво*, а не *пиво*, бо московською пишуть *пиво*, а не *пьіво*?

Comment: @stegetsj, мені здається, Світлана висловлює, можливо, не зовсім чітко, але дуже правильну думку: **якщо** якесь слово — сучасне запозичення з російської, то його вимова _найімовірніше_ (хоча не факт, звісно) відтворюватиме російську вимову, а **якщо** слово спільне праслов'янське, то _найімовірніше_ (хоча не факт, звісно) російській -и- відповідатиме українська -и- (бо зазвичай так виходить етимологічно). Слово «пиво» — гарний приклад слова, що має праслов'янське походження.

Comment: Походження слова «бирка», наскільки я пам'ятаю, точно не з'ясоване. Але найдавніше трапляння, що я бачу, — це Григорій Квітка-Основ'яненко, «Листи до любезних земляків»,1839 — «бирка». Тож конкретно щодо цього слова: навіть якщо вважати, що його походження російське, я однаково схиляюся до вимови/написання через «и», бо за два сторіччя це слово вже більш-менш усталилося саме в такому вигляді.